# Blocking Arizona Termites

Tags: plastic, old-house, termite

So, the termites in Arizona live in the ground, and they make mud tunnels up the side of the foundation of a house to get into the wood. I was thinking, if I make a plastic lip which curls down, and glue it to the side of the foundation, then I could prevent termites from being able to build their mud tunnels up to the house.

I'm thinking something like what's in this image:

[image]
...only turned over so it curls down, and maybe a bit sharper so it's hard to get around the lip.

Your thoughts? Anybody sure this won't work?

Comment: Initial thought is that anything with a curve large enough to prevent them from making a mud tunnel over might be big enough to trap dirt and make a home for spiders or wasps (not sure about other pests in your area).

Comment: I think termites are more creative and inventive than you think. If it was that easy everybody would have done that already.

Comment: It's not a dumb idea but it's been thought of already and is a common requirement in many building codes.  Lookup "termite shield" and you'll see numerous examples.